# Case-insensitive search within discourse console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, discourse

I discovered that using

```
title = 'lowercase and More'
topic = Topic.find_by(title:title)
```

will always return nil as the topic title when saved becomes `Lowercase and More`

I tried using

```
topics = Topic.find_by_sql("select * from topics where lower(title) = '#{title.gsub(/'/,"''").downcase}'")
if topics.length > 0 then
    result = topics[0]
end
```

which resolves `title: 'lowercase and More'` but it brings up other edge cases.

Is there a simple way to do a case-insensitive searches within discourse using the rails console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a validation in model

```
validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
```

Query

```
title = 'lowercase and More'
result = Topic.where('lower(title) = ?', title.downcase).first
```